# Store data in real time in a 2D array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, real-time

I'm having trouble storing real time data in an array.

I have a 1D array that reads data in real time, this is fine and it's printing me data like this:

```
D/this is my array: arr: = [-1.43, -3.5916, 2.71, 4.42, -4.4, 0.0]
```

This data represents ONE sample, and I'm reading data 1000 samples per second, so if I print this array, it shows me reading per reading, I mean 1000 arrays like the picture (with different data) per second.

Now, I need to process that data, so I need to store the first 256 samples in a 2D array, process that array and then get a new one with the next 256 samples and so on.. But I haven't been able to do this.

`transformed` if my 1D array that shows me sample by sample. And `buff` is the matrix I want to store the data into.

This is how I get transformed, it is first short[] and then I'm converting it to double:

```
short[] yaxis = msg.getData().getShortArray(BiopluxService.KEY_FRAME_DATA);
double[] transformed = new double[yaxis.length];
for (int j = 0; j < yaxis.length; j++) {
    transformed[j] = (double) yaxis[j];
}
```

This is what I have so far:

```
double[][] buff = new double[256][6];
for (int f = 0; f < 256; f++) {
    buff[f] = transformed;
}
Log.d("this is my array", "arr: " + Arrays.deepToString(buff));
```

But my buff array has the same values.

Comment: Is transformed a variable, or a method call, if it is a value you are setting all the rows to point to the same array

Comment: I updated the question so you can see how i'm getting transformed

Comment: So you read the values in once, and then set all the rows to the same value? If so that'll be the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Why doesn't the array contain different values

You are setting all the rows to point to the same array, if you run this code:

```
public class ClassNameHere {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      double[][] d = new double[5][];

      double[] row = {1,2,3};
      for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
         d[i] = row;
      }
   }
}
```

Through [this](https://cscircles.cemc.uwaterloo.ca/java_visualize) tool, you can see that at the end of this code all of the rows point to the exact same array, so they will all be equal.

## How to fix

You want to create a new array for transformed each time, and then load into that array, so all the rows are different arrays, allowing them to have different values.

Comment: Okay yeah I understand, but I'm not so sure how to do this. If I create different arrays, like transformed[1] and so, sometime I will get more than 256 transformed, and when that happens I need to restart my 2D array and create a new one with the next 256 transformed. Or I don't know if my not getting it right, could you please show me how?

Comment: You'll want to create a new transformed for each set of readings, load the data into it and then set the buffer at the given index to point to your new array, then repeat this process for each of the items